# Understanding plyr's ddply function

Tags: r, plyr

I am learning R and don't understand a section of the below function.  In the below function what exactly is `count=length(address)` doing?  Is there another way to do this?

```
crime_dat = ddply(crime, .(lat, lon), summarise, count = length(address))
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `ddply` but I would guess `summarise` aggregates a number for unique groups of `lat` and `long`. This number is called count and it is calculated by `length(address)` which should be the number of addresses within each lat/lon group.

Comment: consider using the package `dplyr` instead... if I am right in my above interpretation the equivalent `dplyr` command would be: `crime_dat <- crime %>% group_by(lat, lon) %>% summarise( count = length(address) )`

Comment: I believe it'd be `crime %>% group_by(lat, lon) %>% tally()` or `crime %>% group_by(lat, lon) %>% summarise(count=n())` if one wants to do more summary stats. That `crime` data is in the `ggmap` pkg (if folks want to test) and that exact `crime_dat =` line is from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273444/creating-leaflet-heatmaps-in-r-and-shiny-using-rcharts

Comment: `with(crime, tapply(address, list(lat, long) , length)`. The length() of a vector is just the number of 'address'-items in each cross-category of `lat` and `lon`. (I'm assuming you know what they are.) The length() of a dataframe on the other hand is the number columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `plyr` library has two very common "helper" functions, `summarize` and `mutate`.

Summarise is used when you want to discard irrelevant data/columns, keeping only the levels of the grouping variable(s) and the specific and the summary functions of those groups (in your example, `length`).

Mutate is used to add a column (analogous to `transform` in base R), but without discarding anything. If you run these two commands, they should illustrate the difference nicely.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), summarise, count = length(mpg))
ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), mutate, count = length(mpg))
```

In this example, as in your example, the goal is to figure out how many rows there are in each group. When using `ddply` like this with `summarise`, we need to pick a function that takes a single column (vector) as an argument, so `length` is a good choice. Since we're just counting rows / taking the length of the vector, it doesn't matter *which* column we pass to it. Alternatively, we could use `nrow`, but for that we have to pass a whole data.frame, so `summarise` won't work. In this case it saves us typing:

```
ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), nrow)
```

But if we want to do *more*, summarise really shines

```
ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), summarise, count = length(mpg),
      mean_mpg = mean(mpg), mean_disp = mean(disp))
```

---

> Is there another way to do this?

Yes, many other ways.

I'd second Alex's recommendation to use `dplyr` for things like this. The `summarize` and `mutate` concepts are still used, but it works faster and results in more readable code.

Other options include the `data.table` package (also a great option), `tapply()` or `aggregate()` in base R, and countless other possibilities.